# How to substract floating point numbers with high precision

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I have a number say 5.112
I want to subtract it in each iteration by 0.001
like 5.111, 5.110, 5.109, 5.108 etc.

Currently, I am thinking of using the split method to separate the number form decimal point and then subtract the 1st index by 1 and join.

I am just wondering If there is any other better way of doing this.

Comment: Why not using a for loop and actually subtracting `0.001`?

Comment: @Anwarvic Because [floating point math is (probably) broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4518341) (me paraphrasing the question's title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floats are imprecise (see [Frank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63941912/4518341) and [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4518341)).

Use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html) instead.

```
from decimal import Decimal as D

x = D('5.112')
mille = D('.001')
for i in range(5):
    x -= mille
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
5.111
5.110
5.109
5.108
5.107
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do

```
x = 5.112
while True:
    x -= .001
    print(x)
```

You would quickly see the problems with floating point numbers and accumulating roundoff errors.  The easiest method to avoid this is to instead calculate `5.112 - i * .001`, where `i` is the number of subtractions you've performed so far.

Comment: On my system, `5.112 - 4 * .001` is `5.1080000000000005`. Use `decimal` instead. I posted [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63941991/4518341).

Comment: You identified the problem correctly, but your solution suffers from the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy and list comprehension, like so:

```
import numpy
start = 5.112
[start-val for val in numpy.arange(0, 0.1, 0.001)]
```

You just need to know how many times you want to perform this operation.

Comment: Have you tried your code? The output is not correct.